# Why does `context.screen.metrics.heightPixels` sometimes include the height of the navBar for Android Tablets?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm using `context.screen.metrics.heightPixels` to get the height of the screen so I can then do some calculations for determining the placement of a dialogue window. However, I've found that when testing with tablets, the return value is inconsistent. Sometimes it will include the height of the nav bar, and sometimes it will not. Here is an image visualizing what's happening.

[image]

Due to this inconsistency, I get differing behaviour across devices when I try to use this height value to calculate the positioning of my dialogue window.

Why is this the case? I don't want that extra nav bar height. Is there either a more consistent way I can check the height, or an easy way to remove the navbar height from the equation?